# How can i store a variable data into my database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store a variable that into my database. i have already created a field in my database table that should store the variable. The variable i created is $total which stores calculations as shown in the code below:

```
<?php                           
$user_query=mysql_query("select * from book where status != 'Archive'")or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($user_query)){
$id=$row['book_id'];  
$cat_id=$row['category_id'];
$book_copies = $row['book_copies'];
$borrow_details = mysql_query("select * from borrowdetails where book_id = '$id' and borrow_status = 'pending'");
$row11 = mysql_fetch_array($borrow_details);
$count = mysql_num_rows($borrow_details);

$total =  $book_copies  -  $count; 
/* $total =  $book_copies  - $borrow_details;

echo $total; */
?>
```

i have tried by storing it using the code below

```
<?php mysql_query("INSERT INTO book (borrow_total) VALUES('$total')");?>
```

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_* API. Use `mysqli_*`  or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Comment: What´is your question?

Comment: Do you get any error reported?

Comment: Are you trying to insert a new row on the book table, or update an existing row on the book table?

Comment: is a column "borrow_total" exists in "book" table?

Comment: Don't use "or die(mysql_error()" either. It's good for debugging but if you leave it in when the site goes live it leaks information useful to hackers.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, complete `while` loop first.

Comment: Hope you require update existing data with `$total` value and that's why you should use _UPDATE_ query not _INSERT_. See [more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your question is not complete itself but I thing you want to update the 'borrow_total' field of selected book. So instead of INSERTING, you just need to run UPDATE query as below:

```
<?php mysql_query("UPDATE book SET borrow_total=$total WHERE book_id=$id"); ?>
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking to do an update of the book table. In which case something like this would be normal:-

```
<?php                           
$user_query =   mysql_query("select * from book where status !  =   'Archive'")or die(mysql_error());
while($row  =   mysql_fetch_array($user_query))
{
    $id     =   $row['book_id'];  
    $cat_id     =   $row['category_id'];
    $book_copies    =   $row['book_copies'];
    $borrow_details =   mysql_query("select * from borrowdetails where book_id  =   '$id' and borrow_status =   'pending'");
    $row11  =   mysql_fetch_array($borrow_details);
    $count  =   mysql_num_rows($borrow_details);

    $total  =    $book_copies  -  $count; 

    mysql_query("UPDATE book SET borrow_total = $total WHERE book_id = $id");

}
?>
```

You can do an update using an INSERT if there is a unique key. For example, assuming book_id is the unique key of the book table:-

```
<?php                           
$user_query =   mysql_query("select * from book where status !  =   'Archive'")or die(mysql_error());
while($row  =   mysql_fetch_array($user_query))
{
    $id     =   $row['book_id'];  
    $cat_id     =   $row['category_id'];
    $book_copies    =   $row['book_copies'];
    $borrow_details =   mysql_query("select * from borrowdetails where book_id  =   '$id' and borrow_status =   'pending'");
    $row11  =   mysql_fetch_array($borrow_details);
    $count  =   mysql_num_rows($borrow_details);

    $total  =    $book_copies  -  $count; 

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO book (book_id, borrow_total) VALUES('$id', '$total') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE borrow_total = VALUES(borrow_total)");

}
?>
```

This is trying to do an insert, finding an already existing record so updating the borrow_total column with the value you were wanting to insert. This can be useful when you want to update hundreds of records in 1 statement.

But you can probably do the whole loop / update using one SQL statement, something like this:-

```
UPDATE book b
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT book_id, COUNT(*) AS borrowed_count
    FROM borrowdetails 
    WHERE borrow_status =   'pending'
    GROUP BY book_id
) bd
ON b.book_id    =   db.book_id
SET b.borrow_total  =   b.borrow_total - bd.borrowed_count
where b.status !=   'Archive'
```

Note, as said above the MYSQL_* function are deprecated (ie, support for them has pretty much gone and they will soon be removed from php) so best to switch to MYSQLI_* functions or pdo. I have used MYSQL_* functions here just for consistency with your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mysqli_query();` function instead of `mysql_query();`...Try `mysqli_ query();` function to execute your queries..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert new record in mysql table then

```
<?php mysql_query("INSERT INTO book (borrow_total) VALUES('$total')");?>
```

it should work, and if you want to update a row in your mysql table then

```
<?php mysql_query("UPDATE book SET borrow_total=$total WHERE book_id=$id"); ?>
```